# Dlink DWA-125 connection quality always 0

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, adapter

I use DLINK DWA-125 on my PC as my network card doesn't support wireless connections and have an issue with my adapter using Ubuntu 15.10. I can see a lot of WiFi spots but the connection quality is 0 for each of those spots, even for my own spot which is 2-3 meters away from my PC (I can connect to it, yet it takes a lot of time and then I get ridiculously low connection speed - average ping on google.com is 2700ms). 
I tried to make my notebook function as a WiFi hotspot and then connected to it from my PC to check the connection - it worked, but I could get the connection quality 3/4 and the speed of 2 MB/s only when I put my laptop very close to the adapter. 
I've searched through a bunch of topics on different forums but most of them discuss making visibility of the adapter in Ubuntu, so I could get literally nothing out of that. 
I use clear Ubuntu 15.10 x86 (installed yesterday) and the driver for the adapter was successfully configured during the install.

### I put some info I got from terminal which may be useful:

driver: r8188eu

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2001:330f D-Link Corp. 

$ iwconfig

wlx6c198f894581  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"TP-LINK_B17466"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: C0:4A:00:B1:74:66   
          Bit Rate:150 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=75/100  Signal level=-48 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.
```

### Any help would be MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug with the original module but there are updates from Larry Finger

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu
sudo dkms build 8188eu/1.0
sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
```

Reboot